# Update a Div with a PartialView

Tags: html, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, partial-views

I'm trying to update the Div's value with a Partial-View, but I have no idea what to write into the .html().

My Controller-Methode:

```
public IActionResult UpdateDiv()
{
    return View("_PartialView1");
}
```

My Javascript function:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "/home/UpdateDiv/"
    }).done(function () {
        $("#UpdateDiv").html();
    })
```

The div:

```
<div id="UpdateDiv" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;"></div>
```

My Partial-View:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add a respone param to done callback function? Something like the below code snippet:

```
$.ajax({
       url: "/home/UpdateDiv/"
    }).done(function (response) {
        $("#UpdateDiv").html(response);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get("/home/UpdateDiv/", function(data) {
  $(".UpdateDiv").html(data);
});
```

Try this way. It uses GET method to receive HTML from your action. Once it's done loading, it updates your update div element.